# Reset export PATH back to its default value in Git Bash

Tags: windows, bash, git, shell, path

I am new to bash/shell scripting and need to undo the effects created when I ran the command

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

and

```
export PATH=~/C:\Users\I860605\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts:$PATH
```

I was attempting to troubleshoot a Reuse tool and entered the command thinking it would fix the issue, however as a result none of my commands in Git Bash seem to work any longer, and normal commands for Python and other dependencies now result in `command not found` errors.

I also noticed that now my Git Bash CLI no longer picks up whether I'm cd'd into any of my repositories, with no display of (main) branch etc.

I found some other articles that were somewhat related to this, but they were for Ubuntu and Mac users, not for Git Bash on Windows, which is my scenario.

When I ran the command echo $Path, this is what was returned:

```
echo $Path
/c/Users/I860605/C:UsersI860605AppDataRoamingPythonPython39Scripts:/c/Users/I860605/.local/bin:/c/Users/I860605/.local/bin:C:UsersI860605AppDataRoamingPythonPython39Scripts
```

I saw that I could perhaps run `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.bashrc` and edit the file contents from there, but both commands return `No such file or directory`

How would I go about setting my Path back to how it was before this blunder?

Comment: Can you not just open a new instance of git bash?

Comment: I believe you're right, although I could've sworn I had tried that. Before opening a new instance, I saw that I did not have a .bashrc file in my C/Users/Username/ directory, so I also created one there and added my initial `export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin` to the file. It is working now however. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to open a new session, the simplest approach is:

- to have a `~/.bashrc` (with `~` or `$HOME` set by default to `%USERPROFILE%`)
- set your `PATH` in it (like your `export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin`)
- type "`source ~/.bashrc`": that will reset the `PATH` of the current session.

Type `echo $PATH` to then check the path is indeed at the expected value.